# seleccionar un valor de un select

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando seleccionar el value de este selector, para editar el valor inicial y reemplazarlo por uno nuevo que asigne un usuario. 
pero no consigo dar lo la solución. Me podéis dar alguna sugerencia por favor??.

Muchas gracias

```
<select name="principalIngredient" id="principalIngredient">
    <% principalIngredient.forEach((ingredient) => { %>
      <option type="text" value="<%= ingredient %>" class="form-control"><%= ingredient %></option>
    <%  }) %>
  </select>
```

Comment: Cual de todos es el que quieres seleccionar??

Comment: quiero seleccionar value="<%= ingredient %>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno en primera creo que no es necesario el *atributo* `type="text"` en el `option` ya que puede tomar cualquier valor.

Ademas podrias utilizar JS para este caso

```
<select name="principalIngredient" id="principalIngredient" onchange="setValue(this)">
<option value="<%= ingredient %>" class="form-control"><%= ingredient %></option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function setValue(rece){
     var prcc = rece.value;
  }
</script>
```

asi obtienes el valor que necesitas en el metodo js y puedes hacer lo que necesites con el.

Comment: theboshy, muchas gracias. voy a probar a hacerlo asi.

Comment: Un `onclick` no parace adecuado con un `select`, aun peor aplicado a los `option`s

Comment: veo a lo que te refieres voy a actualizar la respuesta